# Deleting first multi line comments from all *c files

Tags: perl, shell

I have lot of c files in a directory. Each files will start with multi line comment like below and starts with include like

```
#include<stdio.h>. 

   // This is a c File

   // This File does sampling the frequency

   /* This uses the logic ...
   .....
   .....
   */

#include<stdio.h>
```

I need to remove all the comments line at the start of all the .c files if they are present. Some files will not have these comment lines. In that case, it should not do anything. This should remove only the first multi line comments. Subsequent multi line comments should be as it is.

How to do this in perl or shell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The head line does not match the question content?

Comment: Important missing information: That first `#include` was not in your original, I assume it is an editor mistake? What rule for "first comment" applies? Comments before any `#include` statements?

Comment: How would you determine the case "It's not there"? It seems that you would always have to look ahead to see whether there was a `#include` to know whether or not you wanted to delete a multi-line comment. And *who* ever thought of putting includes *BEFORE* documentation.

Comment: Removing a bunch of copyright notices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $skipping = 0;
while (<>) {
    m{^\s*//}           and next;
    m{^\s*/\*.*\*/\s*$} and next;
    if ( m{^\s*/\*} ) {
        $skipping = 1;
        next;
    }
    if ( m{^\s*\*/} ) {
        $skipping = 0;
        next;
    }
    next if $skipping;
    print;
}
```

...or alternatively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>) {
    next if      m{^\s*//};
    next if      m{^\s*/\*.*\*/\s*$};
    next while ( m{^\s*/\*}..m{^\s*\*/} );
    print;
}
```

...AND if you only want to do this for the first multi-line comment, change the match delimiters of the range from curly braces to the "?" character, to read like this:

```
next while ( m?^\s*/\*?..m?^\s*\*/? );
```

Comment: I want to do this only for first multi line comment. The subsequent multiple commands should be prsent as it is

Comment: To be on the safe side create the new files in a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that *all* files start with an include, you could remove all lines before the import:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /^#include/..0' *.c
```

Comment: I want to do this in a loop in the shell script

Comment: `-n` command line option *is* a loop. It uses an implicit `while (<>)` loop around the script.

Comment: You don't need a loop. *.c says all c files and with -n option, perl reads the entire file with an implicit while loop

Comment: @Aki You forgot to mention that the `-n` option uses an implicit while loop.

Comment: i mentioned it, may be bad punctuation :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty easy solution, if `#include` could be considered a stopper:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$RS>;
use English qw<@LAST_MATCH_START>;

*::STDIN = *DATA{IO};
my $old_rs = $RS;
local $RS = "*/";
local $_;

while ( <> ) { 
    if ( m{/[*](?:.(?!:[*]/))*\n(?sm-ix:.(?!:[*]/))*[*]/}m ) {
        substr( $_, $LAST_MATCH_START[0] ) = '';
        print;
        last;
    }
    print;
    last if m/^\s*#include\b/m;
}
$RS = $old_rs;
print while <>;

__DATA__
##include<stdio.h>. 

   // This is a c File

   // This File does sampling the frequency

   /* A mline comment not multi */

   /* This uses the logic ...
   .....
   .....
   */

#include<stdio.h>
```

Notice that I had to change the initial `#include` so that the script works. It seemed simple to me that if I wanted multi-line comments, the simplest solution was to make `'*/'` my record separator, instead of doing a lot of switching on the individual lines.

But the lookahead, requires buffering and made a messier solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$RS>;
use English qw<@LAST_MATCH_START>;

*::STDIN = *DATA{IO};
my $old_rs = $RS;
local $RS = "*/";
local $_;

my ( $rin, $rie );
my $mline = '';
my $buffer;

while ( <> ) { 
    if ( m{/[*](?:.(?!:[*]/))*\n(?sm-ix:.(?!:[*]/))*[*]/}m ) {
        my $split = $LAST_MATCH_START[0];
        print substr( $_, 0, $split );
        $mline = substr( $_, $split );
        last;
    }
    print;
}
$RS = $old_rs;
while ( <> ) { 
    $buffer .= $_;
    if ( /^\s*#include\b/ ) { 
        $mline = '';
        last;
    }
}
print $mline, $buffer;
print while <>;

__DATA__
#include<stdio.h>. 

   // This is a c File

   // This File does sampling the frequency

   /* A mutli-line comment not on multiple lines */

   /* This uses the logic ...
   .....
   .....
   */

#include<stdio.h>
```